# Ivy error while building a project in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, build, ivy

I am an Ivy newbie and I need some help resolving an error. When I try to build my project using netbeans it gives me following error :

```
confs: [compile, runtime, compile-test, runtime-test]
C:\Users\Tejas\Documents\NetBeansProjects\LaitsV3\Laitsv3second\nbproject\ivy-impl.xml:92: impossible to resolve dependencies:

java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Tejas\.netbeans\7.1.1\modules\ext\ivy-2.1.0.jar\cache\resolved-Laitsv3second-Laitsv3second-1.0.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

where as this `Laitsv3second-Laitsv3second-1.0` is being picked up by ivy from ivy.xml file's info tag as follows :

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="Laitsv3second" module="Laitsv3second" revision="1.0" />
```

Can anybody help me identifying this problem? or any pointer for help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this error by adding following to the ivysetting

```
<property name="ivy.default.ivy.user.dir" value="${user.home}/.ivy2" />
    <caches resolutionCacheDir="${user.home}/.ivy2/cache" defaultCacheDir="${user.home}/.ivy2/cache"/>
```

this way it tries to find the cache in the specified directory. Otherwise it tries to find the cache in the ivy.jar file. This may sound stupid but it is what happens.
This is the same problem as reported on ivvybeans forum but it is unresolved yet. https://code.google.com/p/ivybeans/issues/detail?id=103

Answer (score 1):

It works for me too, here is my ivysetting looks like:

```
<ivysettings>
<settings defaultResolver="main" >
    <property name="ivy.default.ivy.user.dir" value="${user.home}/.ivy2" />
    <caches resolutionCacheDir="${user.home}/.ivy2/cache" defaultCacheDir="${user.home}/.ivy2/cache"/>
</settings>

<resolvers>

<chain name="main">
    <url name="repo" m2compatible="true">
        <artifact pattern="http://reposserver/artifactory/repo/[organization]/[module]/[revision]/[module]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]" />
        <ivy pattern="http://reposerver/artifactory/repo/[organization]/[module]/[revision]/[module]-[revision](-[classifier]).pom" />
    </url>
    <ibiblio name="compass" m2compatible="true" root="http://repo.compass-project.org"></ibiblio>
    <ibiblio name="ibiblio" m2compatible="true"></ibiblio>
    </chain>
</resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```